# Renaming multiple columns in one statement with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, alter-table, table-rename

Is it possible to rename multiple columns in a single statement, something along the lines of:

```
ALTER TABLE Users
    RENAME COLUMN userName TO user_name, 
    RENAME COLUMN realName TO real_name;
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**No.**

While other actions can be combined, that's not possible with `RENAME`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)

> All the forms of `ALTER TABLE` that act on a single table, except
> `RENAME`, `SET SCHEMA`, `ATTACH PARTITION`, and `DETACH PARTITION` can be
> combined into a list of multiple alterations to be applied together.

Since `RENAME` is a tiny operation on a system catalog, there is no harm in running multiple statements. Do it in a single transaction to minimize locking overhead and avoid race conditions with intermediate states (which are then invisible to all other transactions).

Other actions like `ALTER COLUMN ... SET TYPE` are potentially expensive because they may have to rewrite the whole table. With big tables it would be wise to do as much as possible in a single statement.