# If i have two columns in table how to interchange columns names in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

for example in my table i have domain and email columns, and data like this email column has something@Gmail.com and domain column has www.something .com i want to change domain column name to email name name if is this possible or not

Comment: please provide some sample data and explain along with it

Comment: Okay, I explained could you help me

Comment: No, you need to be more explicit. Show your table structure, show 2-3 different sample records, and show the *same thing* but with the *same* records how you want them to look after the change.

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE your_table RENAME COLUMN email TO email_temp;
ALTER TABLE your_table RENAME COLUMN domain TO email;
ALTER TABLE your_table RENAME COLUMN email_temp TO domain;
```

Comment: SQL> create table hello (domain number(9),email number(8));

      Table created.

       SQL> alter table hello rename column domain to email;
        alter table hello rename column domain to email
        *
        ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-00957: duplicate column name'

Comment: Ya - That is why I first execute to change `email` into `email_temp` and then the rest.

Comment: if there is  any single query?

Comment: Sort answer no. Longer - [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274679/renaming-multiple-columns-in-one-statement-with-postgresql)

Comment: @sada - why do you need a single "query"? What is wrong with running those three ALTER TABLE (not "queries", really) in succession? Why does the number of them matter?

Comment: That is worked but if there is any possibility to change in single short to get the update

Comment: @sada - I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: You was given for me some "querys" to interchange the column name in table now I edited my question can please see the question again you can understand, and my final intention is if we can change the columns name  in single query or not (is this possible say yes or no) if yes can please explain me

Answer (score 1):

Simple... you'll get the same effect simply by swapping the *data*:

```
UPDATE your_table SET email = domain, domain = email;
```

Plus, it will be done in one transaction.

Comment: i am not asking the data interchange .

Comment: @sada - this is logically equivalent - in other words, you'll get the same **logical outcome** by swapping the *data* over instead of the *column names*.

Comment: -suppose email column have something@gmail.com data and domain column www.sometimes.com what is the logical outcome there no sense to change swapping

Comment: @sada, your question didn't convey that sense at all. So you want to only swap *a portion* of the column values? Please edit your question to make it clearer what your data looks like, and how you'd like it to look after the change.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I will change that(you know my intention to the columns interchange and about my data) could you please help me to find the query