# Alter column type from text[] to jsonb[]

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb, ddl, alter-table

I have a `text[]` column which consists of elements of stringified JSON, and I want to convert it to `jsonb[]`.

Here is my table reduced to the relevant `text[]` column:

```
CREATE TABLE certificate (
  ...
  criterias text[]
  ...
)
```

An example `criterias` column looks like this:

```
'{"{\"url\":\"https://criteria.com\", \"description\":\"My Criteria\"}","{\"url\":\"https://criteria2.com\", \"description\":\"Other Criteria\"}"}'
```

Each criteria is of the same format.

I want to convert the type of the `criterias` column to be `jsonb[]`.
How can I achieve this? I am using Postgres 15.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, [`to_jsonb()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) converts a Postgres array into a JSON array automatically.
But your case is not so simple. You stored `jsonb` literals as elements of a text array (`text[]`). So you must cast each element (or the whole array) to `jsonb` explicitly.

For completely valid JSON literals, there is a shortcut with **direct casts** and `text` as stepping stone. Because the `text` representation happens to be identical. (No custom function required.):

```
ALTER TABLE certificate
ALTER COLUMN criterias TYPE jsonb[] USING criterias::text::jsonb[];
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_KnjwFs6)

To convert to an actual `jsonb` column  (the more commonly used setup), unnest and cast elements individually. I suggest a temporary function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.arr2jsb(text[])
  RETURNS jsonb
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
RETURN (
   SELECT jsonb_agg(elem::jsonb)
   FROM   unnest($1) elem
   );
```

Then:

```
ALTER TABLE certificate
ALTER COLUMN criterias TYPE jsonb USING pg_temp.arr2jsb(criterias);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JJxMz2Yh)

To get an array of `jsonb` values (`jsonb[]`), use a function with `array_agg()` instead of `jsonb_agg()`, and `RETURNS jsonb[]`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.arr2jsb_arr(text[])
  RETURNS jsonb[]
  LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL safe
RETURN (
   SELECT array_agg(elem::jsonb)
   FROM   unnest($1) elem
   );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3RL2g3gT)

The rest is mostly the same. Might be useful to do more than just type conversion. Else the plain cast at the top is simpler.

If the column has a column `DEFAULT`, you may have to drop and recreate that with proper type. See:

- [Convert varchar column to inet](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/214170/3684)

Note that either results in a complete table rewrite, which takes an exclusive lock on the table for the duration. See:

- [Renaming multiple columns in one statement with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274679/renaming-multiple-columns-in-one-statement-with-postgresql/23274931#23274931)
- [Will changing column from timestamp to timestamptz lock the table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480700/will-changing-column-from-timestamp-to-timestamptz-lock-the-table/32481513#32481513)

About temporary functions:

- [How to create a temporary function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990622/how-to-create-a-temporary-function-in-postgresql/31095452#31095452)

About SQL-standard functions:

- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300512/3684)

Comment: I upvoted, but it returns jsonb and not jsonb[]. If you can modify to make it return jsonb[] it would be awesome :)

Comment: I added 2 variants for `jsonb[]` and some pointers.